# Jquery assigning class to th in a table

Tags: jquery, html-table

I am trying to assign class to table headers. I am trying to read class names of td's and assign it to related th header. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<table >
  <tr>
    <th>hdrcol1</th>
    <th>hdrcol2</th>
    <th>hdrcol3</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td class="title">col1</td>
    <td class="desc">col2</td>
    <td class="addclr">col3</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td class="title">col11</td>
    <td class="desc">col22</td>
    <td class="addclr">co33</td>
 </tr>
</table>

$('table tbody tr td').each(function(index){

    if($('tr th').eq(index).attr('class') != ''){
        //put this class on the current td
        $(this).addClass($('thead tr th').eq(index).attr('class'));
    }
});
```

[What I tried in fiddle id here](http://jsfiddle.net/xxBeL/)

Comment: Is your table ALWAYS to be formated this way?

Comment: No this is common example I took, but tds will have classes similarly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You had `thead` in your selector, but there is no `thead` in your table. Also you had your selectors backwards. As you mentioned above, you wanted to be adding the `tr` class to the `th`, not vice-versa (although your comment seems to contradict what you wrote up above).

```
$('tr th').each(function(index){
    if($('tr td').eq(index).attr('class') != ''){
        // get the class of the td
        var tdClass = $('tr td').eq(index).attr('class');
        // add it to this th
        $(this).addClass(tdClass );
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xxBeL/12/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("tr th").each(function(i) {
    var tdClass = $("tr td").eq(i).attr("class");
    if (tdClass != "") $("tr th").eq(i).addClass(tdClass);
});
```